# Jaxb custom binding map

Tags: java, dictionary, interface, jaxb

I need to serialize a object with jaxb. 
This object contain :

```
    private Map<String, List<Interface>> d;
```

When i serialize this object, I obtain this exception : IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces

How to resolve this exception ? use xmladapter  (but how) ?
Thx for your help.

Comment: Yes you will need an `XmlAdapter`.  Here is a link to help you get started:  blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html